# Angular Material Datatable not sorting data from Http request

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-material-6

I am using Angular Material datatable with Http request to get data.

However, it is not sorting data in Data table.

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    "firstname",
    "middlename",
    "lastname",
    "status",
    "dateofbirth"
  ];     
  selected;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Yuvak>();

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private dialogService: NbDialogService,
    private contactService: ContactService
  ) { }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getAllUser().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataSource.data = data.data.user;
      },
      error => {
        console.log("There was an error while retrieving Users !!!" + error);
      }
    )
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
      }
```

above is my ts file. Previously when i was loading data from local json file it was working fine inside constructor. However, now i am getting data from GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for you displayed columns names with the one you are using as columnheader. Every thing else looks ok. If possible post your template file.

Try this after checking your html file.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.contactService.getAllUser().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataSource.data = data.data.user;
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      },
      error => {
        console.log("There was an error while retrieving Users !!!" + error);
      }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace  `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Yuvak>();` with `dataSource: Yuvak[] = []`  and `this.dataSource.data = data.data.user;` with `this.dataSource = data`

Comment: i am using this "data.data.user "because i am accessing my inner nested object.